# SSIS duplicating records. Where should I look?

Tags: ssis, duplicates, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I recently migrated a SQL Server that sends out 3 reports daily. As part of the migration, I have been comparing the old server SSRS reports to the new server reports. Starting last Thursday, the all 3 new reports are showing exactly double the data in all fields compared to the old report.

It sounds like the SSIS job might be running twice, but when I look at the job history I only show 1 successful entry.

The SSIS jobs pull data from a flat file.

I am looking for suggestions on where else to look to resolve this duplicate data. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Lookup module in SSIS. I had got help from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dRIjVhKoKs

Hope this helps :)

[image]